# Magento product categories disappear when trying to add new subcategory

Tags: magento2, categories

MAGENTO2: All of our categories are showing up in the Magento admin category area but when we try to add a new subcategory, all categories disappear on frontend (top menu). After that, when we re-save all categories one by one they appear again. All of our indexes ("Index Management") are on "UPDATE ON SAVE" mode. 
Note: 1) Our portal is hosted on AWS. 2) We use RDS db. 3) We use Redis Cache. 4) We use Magento Category Permission Module strategy.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you have to delete your new subcategories before saving them one by one? Or can you keep them and they get displayed after being saved again?

Comment: It seems like an issue with the flat tables. Anyway, I changed: "Use Flat Catalog Category" from "Yes" to "No" and "Use Flat Catalog Product" from "Yes" to "No", mm.. for now .. it works (no category/subcategory disappears anymore).